# How can i trigger the function based on the value of the dropdown in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with a code, I'm coding a drawing tool for soccer drills like on soccerddrive.com/draw and my problem is that I dont know how I can trigger different functions based on what value is selected on the dropdown. Just for information i use React with UseState and UseEffect.

```
<div>
  <label>Players: </label>
  <select value={selectedPlayer} onChange={handlePlayerChange}>
    <option value="Player 1">Player 1</option>
    <option value="Player 2">Player 2</option>
    <option value="Player 3">Player 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

so every option should draw a player on the field like this:

```
if (addingPlayer) {
  const rect = canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  const newPlayer = { x, y, id: players.length + 1, playerType: props.selectedPlayer }; // Add playerType to the player object
  handleAddPlayer(event);
  setPlayers((players) => [...players, newPlayer]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will happen using useEffect hook

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
  if (selectedPlayer) {
    // your code
  }
}, [selectedPlayer]);
```

Comment: So i would do it like this:

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
  if (selectedPlayer == Player1) {
    // code draw Player one
  } else if (selectedPlayer ==Player2 {
//code
}
}, [selectedPlayer]);

Comment: on update  of selectedPlayer  state you would like to trigger the function ?